Unzip file from hexadecimal string in Python
I have a hexadecimal string beginning with '504B030414...' which should be a zipped XML file.
Using Python, how can I unzip/read this file? Using below, I get "zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file" (string purposely truncated):
import zipfile
import io
original_zip_data = "504B030414..."
filebytes = io.StringIO(original_zip_data)
myzipfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filebytes)

Below linked answer was helpful using type bytes: b'PK\x03\x04...'
Unzip buffer with Python?
Is there a way to convert my string to a similar format, or is my string truly a corrupted/"BadZipFile"?

"I have a binary value beginning with '504B030414...'" Suppose I don't believe you. Exactly what steps would you take to prove this to me, and to explain exactly what you mean by that? Where does the value actually come from? The string that you show in your program can definitely not be used this way.

When you type exactly b'PK\x03\x04' in your program, this means a sequence of bytes where the first one has the numeric value 80, the second has the numeric value 75, the third has the numeric value 3, and the fourth has the numeric value 4. If you type 'PK\x03\x04' instead, that means a string with four characters, where the first is a capital P, the second is a capital K, the third is an end-of-text character and the fourth is an end-of-transmission character.

So those two things are essentially unrelated. But either way, an actual zip file would not contain a string at all. Files only ever contain bytes, and text is just a way that we try to interpret bytes. And either way, "binary value" is barely a meaningful term, and it certainly doesn't mean what you actually have as input in this code, which is also barely a meaningful thing to have in the first place.

Let me put it another way: in your first attempt, where you wrote b"504B030414", let's suppose it were actually cut off there. How many bytes do you think are in this value - what result do you expect, if you try len(b"504B030414") at the interpreter prompt? Now, try it. If you got the wrong result, then you have conceptual issues that need to be sorted out before a clear question can be asked here. If you got the right result, then the problem is probably just with communicating what you really want to do.

@KarlKnechtel Thanks for the replies, and agreed - my question demonstrated both conceptual and communication issues. Will plan to read through your links.
Cheers!

The problem is you need to convert the hexadecimal string to bytes. io.StringIO class is to be used with text data not binary data.
Here is the correct way to go about it:
import zipfile
import io

#Hex string/ Zip file
original_zip_data = "504B030414..."


# Convert to bytes
filebytes = io.BytesIO(bytes.fromhex(original_zip_data))

# Read the file and print
with zipfile.ZipFile(filebytes, 'r') as myzipfile:
    file_content = myzipfile.read('fileinside.txt') 
    print(file_content.decode('utf-8'))

In this example we convert the hex string to bytes, create a file-like object, and then read the file inside the zip file.

This answered my question - I was able to use this with ZipFile.extractall() and uncompress/retrieve the zipped XML file.
Thanks Isaiah!
